# Div in th table

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem. It may be stupid, but I cannot solve it. I have a table, th and in th I want to have a string with name of column and next ot this two arrows to sort it. I tryed to do float:left but it doesn't react. Now my code looks like this:

```
        <tr>
          <th >
             <div>
                <div class='columnName'>Column name</div>
                            <div class='arrows'>
                                <div class="arrow-up-icon"></div>
                                <div class="arrow-down-icon"></div>
                            </div>
             </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
```

And here is my css:

```
.arrow-up-icon {
  background-image: url('here url code');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.arrow-down-icon {
  background-image: url('');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.columnName {
  float: left;
 }

.arrows {
  float: left;
 }
```

Comment: can you create snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.arrow-up-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}

.arrow-up-icon:before {
  content: '↑';
}

.arrow-down-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

.arrow-down-icon:before {
  content:'↓';
}

.columnName, .arrows {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
 }
```

```html
        <table>
        
        <tr>
          <th >
             <div>
                <div class='columnName'>Column name</div>
                            <div class='arrows'>
                                <div class="arrow-up-icon"></div>
                                <div class="arrow-down-icon"></div>
                            </div>
             </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flexbox` properties in your `css`

I added the following `css` to `.arrows`

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

Here is a complete guide to `flexbox properties`:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.arrow-up-icon {
  background-image: url('here url code');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.arrow-down-icon {
  background-image: url('');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.columnName {
  float: left;
 }

.arrows {
  float: left;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th >
         <div>
            <div class='columnName'>Column name</div>
                        <div class='arrows'>
                            <div class="arrow-up-icon"></div>
                            <div class="arrow-down-icon"></div>
                        </div>
         </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

</table>
```